# data suddenly not returning from facebook chat (limits??? changes???)

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, xmpp, facebook-chat

I have an app that integrates with Facebook chat.  It has been working perfectly for nearly a year now.  all of the sudden, I'm noticing that calls don't return data.  After lots of frustration, I removed the app from my account and reset the token.  And it started working agin... sorta.  I was at least now receiving Presence stanzas.  But, Roster and Vcards still don't respond.  After about the third use of the app... it was back to not even sending presence stanzas again. its like adding it and removing it gave me 3 uses and I was cut.

I know this code is right (or has been right for a year).  The challenge / response goes perfectly with a success.. then Facebook just won't send me a roster... or a vcard anymore. I even threw a ping in for good measure to make sure FB was still on the other end, and it sent me back a "feature not supported" response.  So FB is online, I'm auth'd fine... it just doesn't want to respond.

Did facebook change chat somehow?  I reviewed the limited info but it seems it is still XMPP like it always has been... nothing unusual.  And why would a few features work for a few moments after removing and re-adding the app then suddenly stop working again with nothing different on my end?

Confused... any insider on this would be EXTREMELY appreciated.

EDIT:  I noticed something in the response that looks suspect.  After i do a resource bind, in the response, my username portion of my jid is -0.  That doesn't look right except that FB append the resource with an internal identifier?  Is this maybe part of the issue?  Is it a FB bug?  Or is that the way they manage the kids and ignore usernames.

this is the bind response:

-0@chat.facebook.com/home_a91df689_4E362FB0E7D39

EDIT AGAIN:  While testing some other stuff, FB chat just randomly worked and sent me the presence stanzas and my own card... this time the bind response properly identified me. This looks like it might be a platform bug.

-100000216452967@chat.facebook.com/home

Comment: Same happened to me. The lack of documentation make us imposible to check for a chat limit or time window